# USB vs OTG hardware differences

Tags: usb, difference, usb-otg

I understand that OTG requires hardware and software support but I want to understand what limits a normal non-OTG port to act as one(if software supports it)

I mean, if you can send data over USB can't you make it appear as Host AND as Client if you have it pre-selected in the software?

If this question isn't suitable for this forum please redirect me and I'll delete it as soon as possible.

Comment: "*I mean, if you can send data over USB ...*" -- USB is a bus; that's what the "B" in the acronym stands for.  The bus can transmit data, control, and *power*.  There's a master-slave relationship between host and device/gadget.  Host can/will provide power if device requests it.  A host can support multiple device connections using a (root) hub, but a USB .device can connect to only one host, so there are distinct USB host controllers versus USB device controllers.  IOW the hardware requirements also dictate the mode and capabilities of a USB port, e.g.. bus speed and version compatibilities.